# Can anyone tell how image folder generated in mediawiki ? or how images are stored in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I need a logic by which mediwiki generate the image folder and save the image of any page in that folder.
Suppose For Ex - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer in this page a computer image is shown .Now I want to know that how that image is sotred in the server.
The url of the image is 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Acer_Aspire_8920_Gemstone_by_Georgy.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean how the image URL is generated? The numbers come from the first two characters of the md5 hash of the image name.

Comment: Means In a page cricket i uploaded a image cricket.jpg .I want to ask you that this image will be stored in the directory ,How the directory Name is generated .